# SQLSTATE[HY093]: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, pdo

I am new to PDO. I get stuck, now I am here. I tried basic crude in

> PDO and get error invalid parameter: parameter was not defined

from Update part. Please help me?

```
 public function update_by_id($data) {
    $id = $data['student_id'];
    $name = $data['student_name'];
    $department = $data['department'];
    $email = $data['email_address'];
    $city = $data['city'];
    try {
        $sql = "UPDATE tbl_student SET student_name=:name, department=:department, email_address=:email, city=:city WHERE student_id='$id' ";

        $stmt = $this->db_conn->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':department', $department, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email_address', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':city', $city, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if($stmt->execute()) {
            header('Location: view_student.php');
        }
        else {
            echo $this->db_conn->errorInfo();
        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

Comment: `:email` in a query and `:email_address` in a binding See?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `:email_address` use `:email`

```
 $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Because your bind `email_address=:email,` in your query

And you can bind your `$id` too in your code

```
$sql = "UPDATE tbl_student SET student_name=:name, department=:department, email_address=:email, city=:city WHERE student_id=:id";
    $stmt = $this->db_conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':department', $department, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':city', $city, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: They should be binding `$id` too.

Comment: Yaa !! i am adding this also

Comment: Thanks for help. Yea now binding id too.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 $stmt->bindParam(':email_address', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

To

```
 $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

As you are using

```
.., email_address=:email,...
```